# Using 404 for resource response that may not exist

Tags: rest

I have a RESTful service using HAL links. There is a customer resource and a preferredCard resource. A customer does not always have a preferredCard selected.

As the user must be logged in there is no need to pass customer or card id we will pull it from their identity.

PreferredCard url: `GET: <root>/<version>/preferredCard`

I think I have two options.

1) Add a preferredCard link on the customer and return a 404 (NotFound) if there is no preferredCard, otherwise return the preferredCard resource.

2) Don't display a link to the preferredCard on the customer if one doesn't exist.

Any thoughts on what is best here. Worried that in the first option I am returning a 4XX when the client didn't really mess up

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to handle both situations.

If you know the user has no prefered card, don't give them a link to something that isn't going to work. Maybe give them an alternate link to select one.

Equally, if that URL can exist, the user could always come back to it later, even if it has been removed. In this case, you may want to consider a custom 404 pages. The 404 error would let the user know that the resource they wanted cannot be found, but you can still provide some content, perhaps something explaining what is going on (that there is no current prefered card) and offers some useful links, in this case a link to the page where they can create/select a prefered card.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no preferredCard for the customer-resource, then you may want to serve a `createPreferredCard` or `selectPreferredCard`-link instead of just hiding the link to a 404.

This would look like a clean approach to me, since you are hiding stuff that doesn't work, but offer options.